how to correctly type react dynamic components
Error:
Type * is not assignable to type 'never'.   The intersection * was reduced to 'never' because property * has conflicting types in some constituents.

link on example
type OneType = {
  title: string;
  component: 'One';
};
const One = ({ title }: OneType) => {
  return <div>{title}</div>;
};

type TwoType = {
  price: number;
  component: 'Two';
};
const Two = ({ price }: TwoType) => {
  return <div>{price}</div>;
};

type ThreeType = {
  name: string;
  component: 'Three';
};
const Three = ({ name }: ThreeType) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};

const components = {
  One,
  Two,
  Three,
};

type EntityType = OneType | TwoType | ThreeType;

const entities: EntityType[] = [
  { title: 'some', component: 'One' },
  { price: 9999, component: 'Two' },
  { name: 'some', component: 'Three' },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {entities.map((entity) => {
        const Component = components[entity.component];
        return <Component {...entity} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

A solution with a common type is not suitable because there are different entities
https://www.phind.com/search?cache=i2pgvyrsua0qs54n1zpspjib

Sorry, my mistake by paste code. Fixed it.

Do you have to refer to the components with strings? Or could you reference the actual component function type in OneType, etc.? (type OneType = { title: string; component: typeof One; };) That isn't a solution on its own, but it might be a step toward one, so I want to check if it would work for how you're using it.

There must be strings, since the data comes from the server

It's always tricky when you have a union of function types (which is what Component ends up being in your current code). I think I'd approach it a slightly different way: Get rid of the components mapping object and replace it with a switch in a wrapper component:
function Wrapper<T extends EntityType>(props: T) {
    switch (props.component) {
        case "One":
            return <One {...props} />;
        case "Two":
            return <Two {...props} />;
        case "Three":
            return <Three {...props} />;
    }
}

Then in App:
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            {entities.map((entity) => (
                <Wrapper {...entity} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

The switch lets TypeScript know which of the members of the EntityType union is being used, so it knows that the props object is appropriate for the component.
Playground link

This option will work, but it is not concise and creates code duplication. Instead, it's easier to write TS ignore

@РоманВасилаки - Easier, but also more dangerous. And there's very little code duplication, and it's not that much less concise -- remember, you no longer need the components object. So it removes ~5 lines (plus one in App makes 6) and adds ~10. I'll take that over dropping type safety any day. And another benefit: it will show places where the components are used when you do a reference search when refactoring. But hopefully someone will have another approach you're happier with.

I want to be able to use the capabilities of js without limiting them when working with TS.
The project has implemented abstract the function:
mapping(key, object, default, args)
type ConditionFunction = (...args: any[]) => any

export const mapping = (
 condition: keyof any,
 object: Record<keyof any, ConditionFunction>,
 _default: ConditionFunction | any,
 ...args: any[]
) => {
 if (object?.[condition]) {
  return object[condition](...args)
 }

 return typeof _default === 'function' ? _default(...args) : _default
}

for works with various associative mappings

@РоманВасилаки - TypeScript's purpose is to impose limits, also called type-safety. You can choose to opt out of that in situations where you don't want it, but if you do, you lose the very thing TypeScript is there to provide. It's a trade-off, and everyone (or every project) has to make their own decision where to draw that line. You don't get type safety for free. It's your call entirely, you can bypass type checks w/a type assertion or ts-ignore comment, or you can do smth like the above, or (again) maybe someone will suggest a different middle ground you'll be happy with. Happy coding!
